# asp.net dialing codes dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need international dialing codes dropdown control's code with flags. Is there any asp.net free or premium control ? Or any html control/code which I can use with asp.net mvc ?

Comment: how to get international dialing codes form web service or database source? please elaborate by an example?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with jquery, so I'll mention my jQuery plugin which does this: https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input

It's nothing to do with asp.net, but it doesn't need to be.